# Filtering for serverside options in combo

Tags: javascript, combobox, filtering, webix

I'm setting options in the webix combo widget as URL:

```
webix.ui({
  rows:[
    { 
      view:"combo", 
      options:"https://api.myjson.com/bins/c81ir" // test link
    }
  ]
});
```

URL returns static JSON. But as I can see, if options are set as URL, it triggers also the server-side filtering:

```
Request URL:https://api.myjson.com/bins/c81ir?filter[value]=The
```

And in my case such filtering does nothing.

Is it possible to avoid that or should I load options in the separate AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not why, but using a suggest url, seems to have the behavior you expect :

```
webix.ui({
  view:"combo",
  suggest: {
    url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/c81ir" 
  }
});
```

Snippet : http://webix.com/snippet/4d499263